# Extracting information from a .gtf to a new text file using PERL

Tags: perl, file-io, extract, bioinformatics, bioperl

I have the the below .gtf file, i need to extract only 4 variables (chromosome, start/stop codon and transcripst i.d.

```
1       Cufflinks       transcript      11869   14412   1000    +       .      gene_id "CUFF.1"; transcript_id "CUFF.1.2"; FPKM "0.3750000000"; frac "0.000000"; conf_lo "0.375000"; conf_hi "0.375000"; cov "1.470346"; full_read_support "yes";
1       Cufflinks       transcript      11869   14412   444     +       .      gene_id "CUFF.1"; transcript_id "CUFF.1.3"; FPKM "0.1666666667"; frac "0.000000"; conf_lo "0.166667"; conf_hi "0.166667"; cov "0.653487"; full_read_support "yes";
2       Cufflinks       transcript      11869   14412   333     +       .      gene_id "CUFF.1"; transcript_id "CUFF.1.4"; FPKM "0.1250000000"; frac "0.000000"; conf_lo "0.125000"; conf_hi "0.125000"; cov "0.490115"; full_read_support "yes";**
```

My questions is how does a script know to work on a selected file?

Do you used:

(1) `my $file = 'transcripts_selected.gtf'`

(2) Also can this script be used to extract the sected data:

```
say $data->{"chromosome_number"}->{"start_codon"}->{"stop_codon"}->{"transcript_id"};
```

or should:

`BioSeq->new(-chromosome_number, -start_codon...)` method be used?

(3) Finally this scripts is taken from the BioperlHOWTO:

```
my $seq_in = Bio::SeqIO->new( -file   => "<$infile", -format => $infileformat,);
my $seq_out = Bio::SeqIO->new( -file   => ">$outfile", -format => $outfileformat,);
while (my $inseq = $seq_in->next_seq) {$seq_out->write_seq($inseq);
```

- where is says the variables $infile/$outfile should the name of the .gtf file be placed here and the name of the new file with selected data replace $outfile?

Comment: Why don't you look at some beginners perl tutorials so you can get a grip on the basic principles of programming before launching into trying to figure out BioPerl?

Comment: @ialarmedalien Perhaps the only reason for her to write anything in Perl is because of BioPerl.

Answer (score 1):

the easiest way to specify the filenames is to write something like:

```
my $infile = shift;
my $outfile = shift;
```

above the code block from the HOWTO, then type:

```
perl ScriptName transcripts_selected.gtf OutFileName
```

at the command line